# how to display the value of avg function till only two decimal places in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select avg(purch_amt) from orders;
```

I took an average of the amounts and it shows value till many decimal places and I would like to limit it to two decimal places. 
Here's what I have tried:-
    `select cast(avg(purch_amt) as decimal(10,2)) from orders;`
please answer containing both the operations(first average and then conversion). I would like to know the correct syntax of writing both the statements **together**.

Comment: To begin with, when you are talking about **DISPLAY** you need to specify **WHERE**. Second (and here I'm assuming that you have an application that receives the value and displays it), the correct way of assigning roles (meaning, DB with some business logic and user interface) is to let the user interface to handle that.

Answer (score 3):

You can update your query to:

```
select ROUND (avg(purch_amt),2) as Average from orders;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ROUND as

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG(purch_amt), 2) AS 'Average' from orders
```

or if you want to Round all column values before calculating average

```
SELECT AVG(ROUND(purch_amt, 2)) AS 'Average' from orders
```

Comment: it would round the result, what if i just want to take the digits as it is. eg - 147.346

Comment: if you want to round the column values before average SELECT AVG(ROUND(purch_amt,2)) AS 'Average' from orders

Answer (score 0):

My preferred method is to cast to an appropriate decimal value:

```
select cast(avg(purch_amt) as decimal(10, 2))
from orders;
```

This is a bit different from `round()`, although the two generally produce the same result.  As the documentation explains for `round()`:

> The return value has the same type as the first argument (assuming
>   that it is integer, double, or decimal)

That means that what gets displayed in an application might still show more (or fewer) than the number of decimal places.  By changing the type, the application will know how many decimal places should be in the result.

You can see from [this example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/36c570/2) that `round()` does not change the data type -- hence it might not change the representation in a tool.